# Plotly x axis range plot

Tags: graph, plotly, plotly.js

In plotly, how to plot a bar graph with x axis range dates

I want
in xaxis - startDate, endDate and

in yaxis - requestCount

```
[
  {
    "startDate": 1666255095626,
    "endDate": 1666341495626,
    "requestCount": 3
  },
  {
    "startDate": 1666168695626,
    "endDate": 1666255095626,
    "requestCount": 5
  },
  {
    "startDate": 1666082295626,
    "endDate": 1666168695626,
    "requestCount": 2
  },
  {
    "startDate": 1665995895626,
    "endDate": 1666082295626,
    "requestCount": 5
  },
  {
    "startDate": 1665909495626,
    "endDate": 1665995895626,
    "requestCount": 1
  }
]
```

This is the plotly graph json below
You can see I have used a xAxis as string value with start date and end date.
but is it possible to keep the xAxis as date format and still plot the same graph? This will allow the user to zoom the graph by keeping the date x axis format

```
    [
  {
    "x": [
      "1666255095626-1666341495626",
      "1666168695626-1666255095626",
      "1666082295626-1666168695626",
      "1665995895626-1666082295626",
      "1665909495626-1665995895626"
    ],
    "y": [
      3,
      5,
      2,
      5,
      1
    ],
    "type": "bar",
    "marker": {
      "color": "",
      "colorscale": null,
      "size": "",
      "line": {
        "color": ""
      }
    },
    "name": "",
    "line": {
      "shape": "linear"
    },
    "hoverinfo": "",
    "transforms": []
  }
]
```

Comment: So, you want to specify a start and end date in the x axis? Do you have date data to be plotted over x-axis?

Comment: yes. it has to be a single bar for each range. I can use the x axis value as string (startDate - endDate) and plot the graph. but I m trying to keep the x axis in date format.

Comment: Your provided code is not clear, could you please add minimal code to be able to replicate your work and we can help you.

Comment: The provided values for x-axis are string "1666255095626-1666341495626", how do you want to convert them to date?

Comment: actually it is timestamp range
 {
    "startDate": 1666255095626,
    "endDate": 1666341495626,
    "requestCount": 3
  },

i used it as string here to show an example that its possible with string